# Shortest way to reference the stdin string in bash pipe

Tags: string, bash

Suppose I want to add brackets around a string, I could use:

```
echo "foo" | echo "($(tr '' ''))"
```

or

```
echo "foo" | sed -nE s/^.*$/(\0)/p
```

There should be a shorter way. How do I reference the current string without using a hack like `tr`?

```
echo "foo" | echo "(<what goes here?>)"
```

Comment: How about `echo "foo" | echo "($(cat -))"`? Or better yet, just `echo "($(cat -))" <<< "foo"`.

Comment: I'm amazed that there doesn't seem to be a simple $@-like syntax for this.

Comment: `echo foo | xargs printf "(%s)\n"`

Comment: Well it's hard to give a more concise answer, because your example is lacking context. Otherwise you'd just have done `echo "(foo)"`.

Comment: The actual context that I have is `git grep "TEST_[FP]\(C[A-Z]" | sed s/ma/gic/p | tr '\n' '|' | ...`

Comment: You can do `printf '(%s)\n' "$(git grep "TEST_[FP]\(C[A-Z]" | sed s/ma/gic/p | tr '\n' '|')"`. I really suggest you post your end goal and not your immediate problem though, because in shell scripting there are many shortcuts and indirect ways of solving things

Comment: I'll remember the `cat -` for now ... least crazy (but still a bit.)

Comment: @thatotherguy the end goal is actually a string like `C(Name1|Name2|...)`, usable as a regex.

Comment: @FelixDombek Is your end goal really having a regex? It's not using the regex to search for something?

Comment: @thatotherguy It's supposed to be used for a regex-search-replace for which I still have to decide which files I need included. That is (imho) a task my IDE does better.

Comment: Given the comment discussion, I voted to close the question as "unclear what you're asking". Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok, if your goal is to generate a PCRE string for an unknown external tool, then this is one way to go (though it doesn't handle escaping). If the script was going to search and replace in files, I would go a different route

Comment: Since you're already using `sed`, you could just append a couple commands to the existing `sed` command: `<git command> | sed 's/ma/gic/p;1s/^/(/;$s/$/)/'`.

Comment: @glennjackman Sometimes the complete story stands in the way of asking a specific thing. I think the advice given here, `cat -`, is a good reusable building block that I was looking for and other people might be, too. That's not to say that my question/title couldn't be improved, of course.

Comment: given that the `cat -` trick appears to be acceptable for you but that it only works for input that is a single line, what's wrong with simply doing: `a=$(long pipeline); echo "($a)"` ?

Comment: It does? :/ I want to avoid non-pipe syntax because it's contrary to the reading flow.

Comment: "single line" is probably not the right phrase. perhaps "single value" is better. it's the same as your original tr command. btw, you can shorten the sed  version to `sed 's/.*/(&)/'`